# -ErrorAction Stop not work in Copy-Item

Tags: powershell

Simple script:

```
"test" | Out-File "C:\existing_file.txt"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Copy-Item "C:\existing_file.txt" "C:\NonExistingDir\file.txt" -ErrorAction Stop
"hello" | Out-Host
```

I have this output:

```
Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path "C:\NonExistingDir\file.txt".
C:\Users\ESavin\AppData\Local\Temp\d3d410e0-79b3-4736-b7e7-5aba1ab11a12.ps1:1 знак:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  "C:\existing_file.txt" "C:\NonExistingDir\file.txt" -ErrorAction Stop
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

hello
```

Why I get "hello" in output ?? -ErrorAction Stop not work??

update:

this code:

```
"test" | Out-File "C:\existing_file.txt"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Copy-Item "C:\existing_file.txt" "C:\NonExistingDir\file.txt"
"hello" | Out-Host
```

worked as expected. there isn't "hello" in output.

Copy-Item ignore -ErrorAction and use only $ErrorActionPreference ??

Answer (score 5):

As indicated by the help the ErrorAction parameter has no effect on terminating errors, which yours is.

```
    The ErrorAction parameter has no effect on terminating errors (such as
    missing data, parameters that are not valid, or insufficient 
    permissions) that prevent a command from completing successfully.
```

Source: `Get-Help about_commonparameters` and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315352.aspx

Comment: Are you sure it's a terminating error? I don't think so. Try this: `copy x y; copy x y` (assuming that the file "x" doesn't exist). You will see that it executes twice. Now try this: `copy -ErrorAction Stop x y; copy x y` It will only execute the first one.

Comment: Usually exceptions are terminating errors. But since 2012 powershell has received so many changes that this might not be true anymore.
Thus I will not look further into it. I have to mention also that this question has no accepted answer, so the relevance of the thread is reduced even further.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I copy-pasted your two lines in a script, ran it, and everything works fine: I don't see the "hello" appearing. Your "-ErrorAction" should take precedence over any $ErrorActionPreference you would have set at session level.

Comment: You must create "C:\existing_file.txt" on your computer to reproduce my example

Answer (score -1):

You must have either run:

```
Copy-Item "C:\existing_file.txt" "C:\NonExistingDir\file.txt" -ErrorAction Continue
"hello" | Out-Host
```

or set `$ErrorActionPreference="continue"` and run

```
Copy-Item "C:\existing_file.txt" "C:\NonExistingDir\file.txt"
"hello" | Out-Host
```

Those are the only two ways you would have got the output you are showing. So make sure you are doing what you are claiming to do.

Comment: You don'n understand, or I explained bad. I want to STOP scipt execution if copy-item return error. but -ErrorAction Stop do not stop script. Question is "Why" ??

Comment: @Jack128 - that's what I am saying. What you had done should work. Make sure you did do what you said you did.

Comment: Yes. I sure. I opened powershell ise, type 
"test" | Out-File "C:\existing_file.txt"
Copy-Item "C:\existing_file.txt" "C:\NonExistingDir\file.txt" -ErrorAction Stop
"hello" | Out-Host  
and get "hello" in output